# rownum doesnt work sql

Tags: sql, oracle, rownum

im trying to get the most row appears in the table, when i use in rownum i get error: "SQL command not properly ended", there is something else that i can do?

```
 select src_customer ,count(sending.src_customer) as bla
    from sending
    group by sending.src_customer
    order by bla desc
    where rownum=1;
```

Comment: rownums are assigned before the order by clause. Use Top or select *
from (
select src_customer ,count(sending.src_customer) as bla
    from sending
    group by sending.src_customer
    order by bla desc
)
    where rownum=1;

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you want the largest row.  In Oracle 12, you can use the ANSI standard `FETCH` clause:

```
select src_customer, count(s.src_customer) as bla
from sending s
group by s.src_customer
order by bla desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

In earlier versions, you need a subquery:

```
select *
from (select src_customer, count(s.src_customer) as bla
      from sending s
      group by s.src_customer
      order by bla desc
     ) s
where rownum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `WHERE` clause should be after the `FROM` clause.

See [Oracle documentation for more details](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702)

So, your query should be like

```
select src_customer ,count(sending.src_customer) as bla
    from sending
    where rownum=1
    group by sending.src_customer
    order by bla desc
    ;
```